# How can I redirect Unhandled Exceptions from Standart Output or Error Stream to other Streams

Tags: c#, io, console

```
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Testing/RedirectIn.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                           FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 128, FileOptions.None), Encoding.UTF8, true, 8, false));

        Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Testing/RedirectOut.txt", FileMode.Truncate), Encoding.UTF8, 2));

        Console.SetError(new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Testing/RedirectError.txt", FileMode.Truncate), Encoding.UTF8, 2));
```

So I have Set the `In` `Out` and `Error` Streams
But let's say I erite this snippet and I do not catch the exception.

```
int y = 5;

Console.Error.WriteLine(y / 0);
//or
Console.WriteLine(y / 0);
```

The unhandled exception still gets displayed in my Console window but not in my specified `error` and `Out` TextWriters.
Can you please tell me why is that so and how can I make unhandled exceptions information be written not in the console but not in my specified `error` and `Out` TextWriters?